Wear OS Layout Issue: Only Upper Left Quadrant Usable on Samsung Galaxy Watch 4
I'm developing a Wear OS toy app for a Samsung Galaxy Watch 4. Despite what I believe to be correct configurations (i.e. no errors in app building or deploying - except for the "glitch" I will mention here), my app's layout only occupies the upper left quadrant of the screen, with the rest of the screen remaining black. Other apps on the watch use the full screen without issues.
I've verified my layout and manifest XML files, and they appear to be correct. The problem persists regardless of the layout structure I use.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or have suggestions on how to resolve this? here is an example of my activity_layout.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="@dimen/box_inset_layout_padding"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/inner_frame_layout_padding"
        app:layout_boxedEdges="all">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                android:onClick="reset"
                android:text="Reset"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="46dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="20sp"
               app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>

I expect the view to occupy all the watch screen

Try removing BoxInsetLayout to see if you now have access to the whole display.

Unfortunately I still have the same issue even if I remove the BoxInsetLayout. The only quadrant alive is the upper left from 9 to 12 o'clock. The rest is all black. I can't be the only one in the world who has this problem. Or maybe the watch is defective. But other apps downloaded from the market they use the full display without problems.

"I can't be the only one in the world who has this problem" -- I would not rule that out, at least in terms of the specific circumstances that are leading to this effect. What happens when you run your app on a Wear OS emulator? What happens when you build and run some open source Wear OS code on your watch?
